# route public ip of modem into your localhost

Tags: networking, web, ip

we know that if anyone in the world types my public IP in his/her web browser, he/she will see my modem's login page
also if I serve a website on my laptop, anyone in my network can connect to it from my local ip address like `192.168.1.8`

I was wondering if there was a way that if anyone in the world typed my public ip address, he/she would see my website on `localhost` of my laptop.
is there any way to do that!? sth like redirecting, or maybe configuring modem's settings...!?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a free dynamic DNS like http://www.changeip.com/dns.php
2. Redirect on your modem all ports you wish to use to you private IP (laptop)
3. Check if your modem support some dynamic dns service to update it. If don't use your laptop to update with some frequency your dynamic IP on DNS service (like 5-10 minutes).